# NoMethodError at / undefined method `-@' for #<DateTime:0x00000001f18168>

Tags: ruby, datetime, activesupport

I'm trying to use `time.ago` using standalone ActiveSupport, required thus:

```
ruby
require 'active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations'
```

If I try to use it as advised:

```
ruby
time = Chronic.parse(time_string)
time.ago
```

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1):
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:61:in `ago'
```

and if I supply an argument, thus:

```
ruby
time.ago DateTime.now
```

I get this one, which I don't understand at all:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `-@' for #<DateTime:0x00000001f18168>:
    /home/passcod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:62:in `ago'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ago` method is designed for you to be able to add a number of seconds (or other time units) to the current time, e.g. `10.minutes.ago`.

Supplying a full date isn't supported and doesn't make sense as far as I can tell - what would 23rd January 2012 at 2pm.ago mean ?